# Decoding Data Stream From Socket Connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient, serversocket

I have the code below to read from my socket connection.

```
String line = null;
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
}
```

I can successfully connect to it using a TCP client, but when I try and send a message in Hex I am getting unrecognisable characters in return.

I am suspecting I need to convert to ASCII, but how would this be done.

Any help would be appreciated.

- See attached pic for example *

[image]

Comment: Define 'send a message in hex'. Define 'unrecognizable characters'. It sounds like you are sending binary, in which case you shouldn't be using a Reader, or reading lines, at all.

Comment: I have attached a screen shot. Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Readers and Writers are for text. Use the input and output streams directly, or via a BufferedOutputStream with appropriate flushing.